# Set location for liberation missions?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I have been wandering for a while around the map trying to find liberation missions to get more assassins.

Is there a set location for the missions? If so, is there a map I can get for the places of the missions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are only in **Boston** and **New York**

There are **3** Missions in each district

You can find more detail on each one here:

http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-3/Liberation_Missions

There are maps included in the link.